# Error with text in plot | Jupyter - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to plot a simple scatterplot with some data using ggplot2 in R on Jupyter notebook installed through Anaconda. Following is the code I used:

`ggplot(data = df1[1:1000,]) + geom_point(mapping = aes(x = val1, y = val2))`

and the result is the following:

[image]

I am experiencing the same issue with normal plot function. For the command -

```
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10000),y=rnorm(10000))
plot(df[1:1000,1],df[1:1000,])
```

I am getting the following result:

[image]

Here's the sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Amazon Linux Bare Metal release 2012.03

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /home/dmangla/sof/anaconda3/lib/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /home/dmangla/sof/anaconda3/lib/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.7.4     purrr_0.2.3     readr_1.1.1     tidyr_0.7.1    
[5] tibble_1.3.4    ggplot2_2.2.1   tidyverse_1.1.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.13     cellranger_1.1.0 compiler_3.4.2   plyr_1.8.4      
 [5] bindr_0.1        forcats_0.2.0    tools_3.4.2      digest_0.6.12   
 [9] uuid_0.1-2       lubridate_1.6.0  gtable_0.2.0     jsonlite_1.5    
[13] evaluate_0.10.1  nlme_3.1-131     lattice_0.20-35  pkgconfig_2.0.1 
[17] rlang_0.1.2      psych_1.7.8      IRdisplay_0.4.4  IRkernel_0.8.9  
[21] parallel_3.4.2   haven_1.1.0      bindrcpp_0.2     xml2_1.1.1      
[25] httr_1.3.1       repr_0.12.0      stringr_1.2.0    hms_0.3         
[29] grid_3.4.2       glue_1.1.1       R6_2.2.2         readxl_1.0.0    
[33] foreign_0.8-69   pbdZMQ_0.2-6     modelr_0.1.1     reshape2_1.4.2  
[37] magrittr_1.5     scales_0.5.0     rvest_0.3.2      assertthat_0.2.0
[41] mnormt_1.5-5     colorspace_1.3-2 labeling_0.3     stringi_1.1.5   
[45] lazyeval_0.2.0   munsell_0.4.3    broom_0.4.2      crayon_1.3.4
```

I've tried reinstalling the packages but the problem still persists. Kindly tell if anyone knows what's the problem here and how to fix it.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: What was the expected output?

Comment: If you are referring to the fonts not being printed correctly, I suspect some text encoding issue.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to the text printing incorrectly.

Comment: @DivyaManglam Are you trying to print English? What's your `sessionInfo()`

Comment: Yes, English only. Added `sessionInfo()` to the question.

Comment: Have you checked fonts? What happens if you print something on the plot using `text()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with Anaconda not installing fonts by default. The solution is to install some fonts:

`conda install -c anaconda fonts-anaconda`

Comment: Did not work for me. I still see box characters after running this command inside anaconda environment and restarting the environment. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I needed to install the following packages:

```
conda install -c anaconda fonts-anaconda
conda install -c r r-cairo
```

(Only installing the first one did not solve the problem.)