# Plot labels are displayed as hexadecimal ASCII codes in R Jupyter notebook on Linux server

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-irkernel

I use remote Linux server (AWS instance) to run a Jupyter R notebook in browser (Chrome). Plots generated either by base R or ggplot2 display labels as hexadecimal codes. Here is an example:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
hist(x, cex.axis = 2, cex.main = 2, cex.lab = 2)
```

outputs this:

[image]

What could be the problem here? Some Jupyter config parameter? I use ssh port forwarding from my local machine to the server, if that matters.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Marouen Nope, but I switched to an instance with different OS kernel: Linux 5.4.58-37.125.amzn2int.x86_64. Now it works fine.

Comment: which OS is this? if Ubuntu, which version? I realized that my weird plot happened right after I installed xelatex. weird..

Comment: @Marouen It's AWS's version of Linux: https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [@Florian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1315472/florian) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64561705/9335767), installing `fonts-anaconda` and `r-cairo` packages should resolve the problem.

```
conda install -c anaconda fonts-anaconda
conda install -c r r-cairo
```