# R kernel in JupyterLab does not display axis properly

Tags: r, jupyter-lab, jupyter-irkernel

Does anyone know how to fix so the axis are displayed properly in JupyterLab using R kernel? So far I have got this outcome:

[image]

Many thanks

Comment: Looks like an issue with the fonts for this particular renderer. Could you try calling `options(jupyter.plot_mimetypes='image/png')` before running the plot function? Or, if it is already a PNG, then try `options(jupyter.plot_mimetypes='image/svg+xml')`.

Comment: Other options that you could try: 1) `options(bitmapType='cairo')` (after ensuring that you have Cairo installed, e.g. `install.packages('Cairo')`); 2) `options(repr.font.family='DejaVu Serif')` replacing `DejaVu Serif` with a name of font that you are sure you have installed. Please let me know if any of these works or not (and which one).

Comment: Thanks @krassowski for the suggestions. I tried all of them and with not satisfactory results unfortunately.

Comment: Issue already dealt in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61938985/plot-labels-are-displayed-as-hexadecimal-ascii-codes-in-r-jupyter-notebook-on-li Works fine for me now.